# Anayltical Solution for this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{dx_1(t)}{dt} = x_2(t)$

$\frac{dx_2(t)}{dt} = tx_2(t)$

Given the above equations, I would like to analytically solve for $x_2$ and $x_1$ in general terms of their initial conditions. Is that possible? I attempted it and so far by eliminating $x_2$ I get:

$\int_{t_0}^t(dx_1(t)t) = \int_{t_0}^t(dx_2(t))$

After integrating and rearranging variables:

$x_2(t) = t(x_1(t)-x_1(t_0))+x_2(t_0)$

I'm not sure if I messed up by not including the "t" in the integral. Then plugging into the original equation to eliminate $x_2$:

$\frac{dx_1(t)}{dt} = x_2(t) = >$

$\frac{dx_1(t)}{dt}-tx_1(t)+tx_1(t_0)-x_2(t_0) = 0$

I'm not sure if I can solve that equation using conventional methods or not?

Comment: Is the RHS of the second equation $tx_1(t)$? Otherwise it is very easy to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the second equation to find $v_2(t) = C e^{t^2/2}$ with $C$ is constant, and then substitute $v_2$ into the first equation to find $v_1$.

Comment: Yes, I corrected my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I also solved it by the method of integrating factors. I really had to dig back to my differential equations book.